# React Native app doesn't launch on Android emulator or physical device

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

I am trying to launch a React Native app and after running `expo start` and pressing `a` I get the following message:

`Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.`

`› Opening on Android...`

`› Opening exp://192.168.1.7:19000 on Pixel_6_API_30`

`› Press ? │ show all commands`

`Android Bundling complete 1685ms`

The app is opened on the Pixel 6 emulator but it closes the Expo Go app before loading and I receive no error messages except for `Expo Go keeps stopping`.

I also tried scanning the QR code and running it on my Android device but had the same issues.